# How to break a list in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am doing [this](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/135) exercise.

Here's my solution:

```
(defn infixcal [left op right & expr]
  (let [r (op left right)]
    (if (nil? expr)
      r
    (infixcal r expr))))
```

When i pass expression `38 + 48 - 2 / 2`, I get ArityException because `expr` is gathered in a list `'(- 2 / 2)`.

The question is how to break it into several arguments and pass it into the next call of function infixcal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want the function apply: http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/apply

This function takes another function f as its first argument and a list l as its second. The function f is then applied to the list of arguments (and the return value is returned from apply).

Comment: Thanks buddy. I didn't figure apply out until reading the docs carefully today.